# Can you mark a file to never be merged in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge

I have a group of several projects that are interconnected and some projects require the build files from other projects.  For several reasons we have committed build these prerequisite build files to the repository.

Every time I try to merge changes from a branch into the trunk or vice-versa, these files will always conflict as they are binarys.  If required, I can rebuild the files from the source project before committing the merge.

However it is really annoing to have to always type "mf" for "mine-full" when doing the merge.

Is it at all possible to permanently mark a binary file as not-mergable in SVN so that it will just always assume mine-full?

I am open to simple scripts if this makes it possible.

P.S.  Please do not turn this into a discussion on whether or not it is a good idea to commit build files to a repository.

P.P.S I am using SVN client 1.7.8 with an SVN server 1.7.5.

Comment: Why dont you remove those binary files from the repository ?

Comment: As I said, I need them for input files in other projects.  These binarys don't change so often and it takes a long time to compile them.

Comment: I just found this property that might help you "svn:needs-lock"

svn:needs-lock Prevents conflicts for files which can not be contextually merged. i.e. photos, binaries, object libraries.

**svn propset svn:needs-lock yes file_path**

Comment: Just tried it.  Doesn't look like svn merge looks for svn:needs-lock.  Good idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two choices

- Replace dumb merge by sequence of two merges: first merge will merge **only** your binaries with special options: `svn merge -q --accept 'mine-full' ...`, second merge merges tree
- You can define in Subversion special merge-tool, *in which* you process you binary special way (same merge as above): use [mergewrap.bat](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.merge.ex-2) and the whole "Using External Differencing and Merge Tools" [section from SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) as starting point

Comment: I see.  Then I could just define a list of files that the script would operate on.  One thing though, is there a way to tell SVN to use its internal libraries for the normal files?  I suppose I could use the GNU tools in the script, but it would be nice to just let SVN take care of the majority of the files as normal.

Comment: While I haven't had a chance to test this thoroughly because I don't currently need to merge right now, I'm marking this one as the answer. I will probably perform the first bullet point using a script since, per my comment above, the second bullet point would require external tools for all files (I believe.)

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber - sorry for delay, I still haven't better solution for replacing merge-tool on the fly than try to use `--config-option ARG` in usual `svn merge command. I.e you instead of hardcoding mergetool in config you can replace it in single merge

Comment: If I use a script to run svn merge in the first place, I think you're first bullet point will work just fine.  I think it might create a mess with the svn:mergeinfo properties, but the script could also take care of that.  I had the idea that I would set a property on the files that I want to make "un-mergable".  It looks like SVN cannot yet perform a search for files with a particular property, but the script could perform a dry-run merge, extract the files to be affected, then look for the property on all of those files.  I'll post a script in a new answer when I make it.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber - "It looks like SVN cannot yet perform a search for files with a particular property...", but (surprise!!) it can: "svn propget -R" in the root, or instead direct search (I'll prefer) use special property in **predefined place** with any custom name and multiline content "FULLPATH PROPERTY" and parse this special property

Comment: so if I understand you right, you are suggesting that I make a property in say, the trunk, which contains the file name to these un-mergable files.  That sounds like a good idea!